# Pegar elemento pelo seletor css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, seletores

Tenho uma `div` em que quero pegá-la pela função `document.querySelector` mas não consigo

A div:

```
<div class=" f:.9 m-b:.4 m-t:.5 d:i-b ">Conteúdo</div>
```

tentei fazer `document.querySelector('div.f:.9 m-b:.4 m-t:.5 d:i-b')` mas não consegui

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tente isso:**

```js
// Exemplo
let queryScape = document.querySelector(`.f\\:\\.9.m-b\\:\\.4.m-t\\:\\.5.d\\:i-b`);

queryScape.style.background = 'red';

// Código
//document.querySelector(`.f\\:\\.9.m-b\\:\\.4.m-t\\:\\.5.d\\:i-b`);
```

```html
<div class="f:.9 m-b:.4 m-t:.5 d:i-b">Conteúdo</div>
```

### Explicação:

Os caracteres ' **:** ' e ' **.** ' na classe entram em conflito com os seletores normais do CSS para classe e atributos especiais, tipo :nth-child ou :last-child, por isso, quando se usa esses caracteres no nome da classe, é necessário "escapar" a query de seleção

Para escapar, basta usar '\\' antes do caracter especial.